# Ubound and In bound runtime error 9 vba( error only on one system works fine on all the other systems)

Tags: excel

VBA runtime 9 error subscript out of range on only one system works fine on all the systems( error near ubound and lbound)

This code worked fine for years later it is giving an error on only one system. 
I have tried updating the excel software and changing the data types for irow and icolumn. Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub TechHR_Refresh_Staffing(sDate As String, sLocationName As String)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim sOrderDate As String
Dim sProtocolHost As String, sQueryServlet As String, sEditType As String, 
sMeasure As String
Dim sSheet As String, sTable As String
Dim sURL As String, sPost As String
Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long, i As Long, j As Long

If (sLocationName = kLocation_Lamar1NRD) Then
    sSheet = kSheet_StaffingData
    sTable = kTable_StaffingTotals
ElseIf (sLocationName = kLocation_Lamar2NRD) Then
    sSheet = kSheet_StaffingDataL2
    sTable = kTable_StaffingTotalsL2
ElseIf (sLocationName = kLocation_Lamar1CP) Then
    sSheet = kSheet_StaffingDataCP
    sTable = kTable_StaffingTotalsCP
Else
    sSheet = kSheet_StaffingDataCPL2
    sTable = kTable_StaffingTotalsCPL2
End If

Set ws = MIRGetNamedSheet(sSheet)

ws.Columns(1).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm"
ws.Columns(2).NumberFormat = "@"
ws.Columns(3).NumberFormat = "@"
ws.Columns(4).NumberFormat = "0"
ws.Columns(5).NumberFormat = "0"
ws.Columns(6).NumberFormat = "0"

sOrderDate = Replace(sDate, "-", "")

sURL = kProtocolHost + kQueryServlet
sPost = "__JSScript=SOS_TempCalculator&__orderdate=" + sOrderDate + 
"&__location=" + sLocationName

If WQ_RunQuery(sURL, sPost) Then

    'Reading results and displaying them
    Dim aResults() As String
    Dim bHasResults As Boolean

    iRow = 0
    While WQ_ParseResults(aResults)
        For i = LBound(aResults, 1) To UBound(aResults, 1)
            iRow = iRow + 1
            iCol = 1
            For j = LBound(aResults, 2) To UBound(aResults, 2)
                ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = aResults(i, j)
                iCol = iCol + 1
            Next j
        Next i
        bHasResults = True
    Wend


   'Code error in the line below
    iRow = UBound(aResults, 1) - LBound(aResults, 1) + 1
    iCol = UBound(aResults, 2) - LBound(aResults, 2) + 1
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(iRow, iCol))

    ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes).Name = sTable
End If

Exit Sub
```

End Sub

Comment: The error is in the line near the bottom where I have mentioned in the comments. 
                                                                                                                               Code error in the line below
    iRow = UBound(aResults, 1) - LBound(aResults, 1) + 1
    iCol = UBound(aResults, 2) - LBound(aResults, 2) + 1
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(iRow, iCol))

    ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes).Name = sTable
End If

Exit Sub

Comment: How is `aResults` populated?

Comment: I think it is populated from the host url.

Comment: I mean what's the code? You don't actually appear to check that it is populated before trying to use it.

Comment: Right, but since it runs on all the other systems, so I thought it should populating the data properly. I am not sure if this answered your question. Because this code was written by someone earlier and since there is an error I'm trying to fix the issue.

Comment: It doesn't really answer it. The only way I can see you getting that error is if the array isn't initialised, or isn't a 2D array.

Comment: I'm sorry, as I am using Excel VBA for a very limited time, I was not able to answer your question. It would be great if you can tell me if I have any options where I can try some trial and error methods with the code and check if the code works,